# How do I rebuild a corrupt dpkg status file?

Tags: bash, dpkg

Whenever I type `sudo apt-get remove` and then press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key for auto-completion I get the following message:

```
grep-status: /var/lib/dpkg/status:15945: expected a colon
.
```

I don't see anything especially strange at line 15945 in the status file.  It's a dot character in the description field of a mono library package and inserting a colon did not help.  Removing the line containing the dot did not work either.  Overwriting the file with status-old resulted in the same message.

Is there some way to rebuild the status file?

Comment: I don't think you can fully rebuild the `status` file: it's a primary source of information, and while a lot of it is redundant, not all of it is. However it's probably possible to repair the file manually. Post a chunk of the file around the problematic line, say 20–40 lines including at least one `Package:` line before and after line 15945.

Comment: I have since tried uninstalling mono but all it did was change the line number that gets reported as an error.

If you follow the paste link, the offending line number is 25, "Section: python"

http://paste.ubuntu.com/501929/

Comment: @Ramón So, `apt-get`, `dpkg` and friends still work correctly, and what is erroring out is auto-completion?

Comment: Correct.  It seems to only be having problems parsing the status file when using auto-completion.  I can otherwise install and remove packages without any apparent errors.

Comment: Getting the same problem. I don't think blindly using an old version of apt's database is the right thing to do here regardless of it fixing *this* problem.

Comment: Oli, you are correct.  You should not blindly use a backed up version, but it seems there is no way to rebuild the status file automatically.  You can use a backed up copy as a reference for manually repairing the file.  If I ever get the time and motivation, I will try to write a script that identifies the corrupt entry.

Comment: Is the file very different from its backup? `diff /var/lib/dpkg/status{,-old}`

Comment: @arrange I've updated my question with more information. @nejode Thanks — I wonder why the search function [failed](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fdpkg%2Fstatus) when I tried looking for similar questions earlier.

Comment: Apparently related: [Corrupt dpkg status file](https://askubuntu.com/q/527064/325633) and [How to recreate /var/lib/dpkg/status?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1102547/325633) (on AU), [How to recreate /var/lib/dpkg/status?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/161866/80216) (on U&L) and [Sudo apt-get error: flAbsPath on /var/lib/dpkg/status failed - No such file or directory](https://superuser.com/q/1216965/354511) (on SU).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have finally fixed my system of this. Restoring a backup of the status file didn't work as I've had the issue for so long, it's in all of my backups.

The fix involves grepping for the actual formatting breaks and fixing them manually. It's not as hard as it sounds.

http://thepcspy.com/read/fixing-dpkg-status-corruption/

Comment: Glad you found a solution, Oli and thanks for sharing.  In my case, in addition to the problematic Lexmark deb, a Webmin deb also had its description malformed but in that case it did not cause any parsing issues when doing an autocomplete.  Weird.

Comment: @Oli are you holder of the licence? Can you write that here?

Comment: This is true, good that I read your post. I had a `missing package name` and I found out that, for some weird reason I better not waste my time finding out, I had a line `Packaga: landscape-common` which was fixed ortographically and bam, problem solved. The thing is, I have never touched this file, nor has anybody else. How can a computer mess up with a spelling mistake?

Comment: The actual answer should be here as well, to avoid it being a link-only answer [if the error's from a blank line that does not precede "Package:" then add a `.` to that blank line].

Answer (score 26):

You should be able to work with a previous known good status file and update from there. Every time you do an install or a update, the status file is saved to a gzipped backup under */var/backups*. Doing an *ls -l dpkg* * on the directory shows:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2266732 2010-09-30 08:35 dpkg.status.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    624182 2010-09-29 08:49 dpkg.status.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    623844 2010-09-28 08:55 dpkg.status.2.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    620358 2010-09-24 11:04 dpkg.status.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    619021 2010-09-23 15:34 dpkg.status.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    619013 2010-09-23 08:03 dpkg.status.5.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    618968 2010-09-21 08:33 dpkg.status.6.gz
```

There's also a backup of the file created in the /var/lib/dpkg/ directory named status-old. Doing an *ls -l status** on the directory shows:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2266732 2010-09-30 08:35 status
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2267191 2010-09-30 08:35 status-old
```

So, to recover from a corruption, you should be able to do the following:

**1. Make a backup of the corrupt status file**:

```
mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status_bkup
```

**2. Copy an recent dpkg status file into place from either of the sources above:**

**either**

```
cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**or**

```
cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.#.gz /var/lib/dpkg/
gunzip -d /var/lib/dpkg/dpkg.status.#.gz 
mv /var/lib/dpkg/dpkg.status.# /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**3. Then run apt-get update:**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

That should do it.

Comment: I did not know about the status files kept in /var/backups.  This is good info to have in case it happens again.  Thanks, Jim.

Comment: But is it safe to use an old version? I mean, surely it's not just the auto-complete that uses this file and using an old version with older package information is going to screw other, far more more important things... like apt itself.

Comment: @Oli I am not sure. I've only had to do this once. I think I had to reinstall the app that was causing the problem, but going forward it worked. As with all advice on the Internet (or at least advice from me on the Internet), this worked for me. That doesn't mean that it will necessarily will work for you. I offer it without warranty and without express knowledge of how it will behave on your system. Your mileage may vary. Try at your own risk.

Comment: This solution appears to have fixed my problems. I will update if any issues arise from using an old status file.

Comment: Old file may be missing some package changes that have done to the system but mostly it will be okay. Doing `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` should fix most of the problems that old `status` file might cause. If your system has a bigger mess, `sudo aptitude dist-upgrade` instead of `sudo apt ...` may sometimes suggest better ways to fix the breakage.

Comment: Why don't you just create an empty status file and run apt update?

Comment: Thank you! This works for me.

Answer (score 7):

Try a "dpkg -P " for the offending package. That will purge it from the local repository, removing all traces. On my system, that was the fix for removed (but not yet purged) packages that produced that error.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to fix this problem by removing the packages which had corrupted entries in the status file.

```
sudo dpkg -r handbrake-cli
```

The accepted solution via pcregrep didn't work (pcregrep didn't find anything).

Comment: Thank you so much it works for me and in fact it is the right approach Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In this case I would back up the corrupted `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file and then correct it manually (around the lines 1888 and 9550) using the information from

```
apt-cache show libssl0.9.8
apt-cache show udev
```

Comment: [Got it](http://paste.ubuntu.com/578090/). apt-get is now running smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

This has been a bug (supposed to be fixed): [Launchpad Bug 613018](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/613018)

Upstream: [Debian Bug 590885](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=590885)

This should be a workaround (backup, "fix" version string):

```
cp /var/lib/dpkg/status ~/dpkg-status.back
sudo sed -i "s/56127_Ubuntu_karmic/56127Ubuntukarmic/" /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 2):

Son of a...

Okay, the actual error was on line 15266 despite it being reported some 700 lines further down.  The problematic entry in the status file was caused by a deb I installed to get my Lexmark printer working a long time ago.  The entry was for the package `lexmark-inkjet-08-driver`.  The Description field did not have a `.` in the place of a line break.  This caused the parsing error.

To find this, I resorted to a shotgun troubleshooting method and started trying things pretty much randomly.  One of my goofy attempts was `grep-status -P e` figuring that e was the most common letter in the alphabet.  Dumb, I know, but the last status record printed out before it complained about a missing colon was for the lexmark package and I noticed the lack of a `.` character after a few minutes of staring at the screen.

If possible, I would like another answer that could describe a better method for finding this sort of issue in case someone runs into a similar problem in the future.  Thanks.

Comment: `grep-status -r -P ^` should always match any package so it should parse the whole file and abort if it cannot parse it.

Answer (score 2):

Because my **status-old** was too problematic even with `apt-get update`,

This worked pretty well for me:

(as root)

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg 

cp -avf status status.corrupt

tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < status.corrupt > status
```

> This command uses the -c and -d arguments to the tr command to remove
>   all the characters from the input stream other than the ASCII octal
>   values that are shown between the single quotes. This command
>   specifically allows the following characters to pass through this Unix
>   filter:
>
> octal 11: tab
>
> octal 12: linefeed
>
> octal 15: carriage return
>
> octal 40 through octal 176: all the "good" keyboard characters
>
> All the other binary characters -- the "garbage" characters in your
>   file -- are stripped out during this translation process.

CREDIT: http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/how-remove-non-printable-ascii-characters-file-unix

If you're curious what's changed or where would be the damage: (possibly long)

```
diff /var/lib/dpkg/{status-old,status} |less
```