# How can I clean up `/var/lib/dpkg/status`?

Tags: dpkg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I rebuild a corrupt dpkg status file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4834/how-do-i-rebuild-a-corrupt-dpkg-status-file)

My system constantly complains about errors in my dpkg status file, and nothing I have tried from the internet seems to work. I could fix it manually- if I could get the file to load in under an hour.

For example:

```
dpkg-query: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 116506 package 'virtualbox-3.1':
error in Version string '3.1.2-56127_Ubuntu_karmic': invalid character in revision number
```

Is there some command I can run to get dpkg to stop complaining about packages I removed two years ago?

Update:

Geany loads it fine, now I need someone to tell me what to remove/change to get rid of these obnoxious messages :).