# dpkg error: "Could not exec dpkg! E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100) "

Tags: 13.10

I am using ubuntu 13.10, and I have deleted the `dpkg` directory. I removed `/var/lib/dpkg`, after the system gave me an error like:

```
Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

when i was installing ubuntu-restricted-extras.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have to restore dpkg's directory in the following state:

```
$ ls /var/lib/dpkg/ -l
total 12543
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4128 апр.   8 13:01 alternatives
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      11 сент. 10  2013 arch
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3075761 апр.   8 13:15 available
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3075761 апр.   8 13:00 available-old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       8 апр.  24  2013 cmethopt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2052 апр.   2 07:51 diversions
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2096 апр.   2 07:50 diversions-old
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  483752 апр.   8 13:16 info
-rw-r----- 1 root root       0 апр.   8 13:16 lock
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      48 марта 23  2013 parts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     288 февр. 12 11:45 statoverride
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     260 февр. 12 09:58 statoverride-old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3081465 апр.   8 13:16 status
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3082826 апр.   8 13:15 status-old
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     744 апр.   8 13:00 triggers
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      48 апр.   8 13:16 updates
```

The problem is that you cut the branch on which you sit. The simple reinstallation of dpkg doesn't work because it's dependent on the directory you have deleted. Fortunately, [we have dpkg status file backup in `/var/backups`](https://askubuntu.com/a/5175/171636). So you have to do this:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg
sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/updates
sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/available
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
```

After this, you should be able to use `apt-get`. And at last, one good advice: ***don't delete any file/directory in the system unless you know what are you doing!***

Comment: when i run last step "sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg" it gives me an error                                            Could not exec dpkg!
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)       what should i do now??? :(

Comment: What is the output of `ls -la /usr/bin/dpkg`?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 256168 Oct  4  2013 /usr/bin/dpkg

Comment: Strange. Download dpkg and try to unpack it. Do not overwrite `/var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: Do it like [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1856256&p=11325182#post11325182). Just replace that `dpkg` with one in `/var/cache/apt/archives`

Comment: ERROR 407: Proxy Authentication Required.

Comment: Do not use wget. You already should have dpkg in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

Comment: then what should i use instead of wget

Comment: yes i have dpkg..                      dpkg_1.16.12ubuntu1_amd64.deb
dpkg-awk_1.2_all.deb

Comment: Unpack it as shown and place appropriate directories in appropriate places. Do not overwrite `/var/lib/dpkg/status`.

Comment: now when i run command apt-get update then it gives me error "E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
"

Comment: or unable to connect 172.16.2.1:3128

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process

Comment: when i run sudo apt-get upgrade then error comes "E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
"

Comment: You have to initially repair your `dpkg` then you can run `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: And for the problem to be resolved, improve your question by _editing_ it. Include full output of the commands.

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libtsan0_4.8.1-10ubuntu9_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libquadmath0_4.8.1-10ubuntu9_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libitm1_4.8.1-10ubuntu9_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgomp1_4.8.1-10ubuntu9_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-4.8-base_4.8.1-10ubuntu9_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)