# Unable to install anything on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt

Whenever I try to run any apt-get command, it gives me this error message:

> dpkg: error: corrupt info database format file '/var/lib/dpkg/info/format'
>
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Please advice how to rectify this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I rebuild a corrupt dpkg status file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4834/how-do-i-rebuild-a-corrupt-dpkg-status-file)

Comment: Is this a duplicate? It sounds like the error is happening in different files, which would mean that the fix could be completely different.

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete that "format" file, or if you're paranoid, back it up (move it to the RAM disk):

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/format /dev/shm
```

Mine only contains the number `1` and a carriage return (`\n`), resulting in a two byte file. You can create this from the command line:

```
sudo printf "1\n" > /var/lib/dpkg/info/format
```

If it fails, then simply restore your backed up "format" file over the top of the new one you created.

```
sudo mv /dev/shm/format /var/lib/dpkg/info/
```

Comment: Are there any risks with doing this? Could you [edit] to include them, and a rm command so that we are less likely to delete the wrong file?

Comment: If you're paranoid, then do this: sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/format /dev/shm which will move the "format" file into the RAM disk, then create a new file using your favourite text editor (type in 1 then enter, then save your file). If it fails, then simply mv /dev/shm/format /var/lib/dpkg/info/ which will restore your backed up "format" file over the top of the new one you created.

Comment: Nope, I am not able to edit this file.

>mewtomat@MewtoMat:~$ sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/format /dev/shm
>[sudo] password for mewtomat: 
>mewtomat@MewtoMat:~$ sudo printf "1\n" > /var/lib/dpkg/info/format
>bash: /var/lib/dpkg/info/format: Permission denied
>mewtomat@MewtoMat:~$ sudo mv /dev/shm/format /var/lib/dpkg/info/
>mewtomat@MewtoMat:~$

Comment: Do "sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/info/format" and then when the editor appears, type in "1" then Enter, then press CTRL+X, then "Y" and then Enter to save your changes.