# Corrupt dpkg status file

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

After upgrading my system last week the S hits the Fan.
Looked al over the forun but did'nt got the answer to solve my problem.
Within DPKG the "status" file was corrupt, back-ups where empty so tried to recover with:

```
(for d in /usr/share/doc/* ; do printf 'Package: %s\nStatus: install ok installed\n' $(basename $d) ; done ) > ~/status
cp ~/status /var/lib/dpkg/
```

My installation:

> Virtual server, OS template ubuntu-12.04-x86_64 + Plesk Client server
>   with mail and sites

As told after recovery te status file i run:

```
root@justme:~# sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  adduser apt-utils base-files base-passwd bash bash-completion bsdmainutils bsdutils busybox-initramfs coreutils cpio cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin dash dbus debconf-i18n debianutils diffutils
  dmsetup dpkg e2fslibs e2fsprogs ecryptfs-utils file findutils gcc-4.6-base gettext-base grep gzip hostname ifupdown initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initscripts insserv iproute keyutils
  klibc-utils libacl1 libapt-inst1.4 libapt-pkg4.12 libatm1 libattr1 libblkid1 libbz2-1.0 libc-bin libc6 libcomerr2 libcryptsetup4 libdb5.1 libdbus-1-3 libdevmapper1.02.1 libdrm-intel1
  libdrm-nouveau1a libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libecryptfs0 libexpat1 libffi6 libgcc1 libgcrypt11 libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-data libgpg-error0 libgpm2 libkeyutils1 libklibc liblocale-gettext-perl
  liblzma5 libmagic1 libmount1 libncurses5 libncursesw5 libnih-dbus1 libnih1 libnspr4 libnss3 libnss3-1d libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-runtime libpam0g libpciaccess0 libpcre3
  libplymouth2 libpng12-0 libpopt0 libreadline6 libselinux1 libslang2 libsqlite3-0 libss2 libssl1.0.0 libstdc++6 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtext-wrapi18n-perl libtinfo5 libudev0
  libuuid1 libxml2 login lsb-base lsof makedev mime-support module-init-tools mount mountall multiarch-support ncurses-base ncurses-bin netbase original-awk passwd perl-base plymouth
  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text procps psmisc python python-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal readline-common rsync sed sensible-utils sgml-base shared-mime-info sysv-rc sysvinit-utils tar tzdata
  udev upstart util-linux uuid-runtime xml-core xz-utils zlib1g
The following packages will be upgraded:
  debconf
1 upgraded, 141 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/38.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 118 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg-query: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 15 package 'acl:i386':
 blank line in value of field 'Original-Maintainer'
' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters `-+._')install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
W: Encountered status field in a non-version description
```

Can someone help..?? Looked almost everywhere.

Comment: Have you tried: http://askubuntu.com/a/5175/158442

Comment: To muru: yes i found that tread as wel, still got the errors

Comment: Also related: [How to recreate /var/lib/dpkg/status?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1102547/325633), [How to recreate /var/lib/dpkg/status?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/161866/80216) (on U&L) and [Sudo apt-get error: flAbsPath on /var/lib/dpkg/status failed - No such file or directory](https://superuser.com/q/1216965/354511) (on SU).

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug for sure.

Try the following, in order, until your problem is fixed.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If that fails try

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/available
sudo dselect update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Or if all else fails

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/{status,available}
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If that fails, you will need to edit the file and remove the offending line or file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. i'll try and comeback with results:

Comment: output of: sudo dpkg --configure -a -> ' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters `-+._')install-info

Comment: keep going to the next set(s)

Comment: Next: sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies: (lot of packages)

Comment: Next:  sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
1 upgraded, 698 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/343 MB of archives.
After this operation, 935 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters `-+._')n specifier 'install-info

Comment: Next: sudo dselect update -> dselect: no access method is selected/configured

Comment: just run those commands and try removing the files. If it fails you will need to manually edit the file or file a bug report.

Comment: Did you mean `sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade` ?

Comment: Lets start off with the ever so slightly, error, error error from removing main dpkg files like status, one its removed i hope you know what you're doing, cause sudo apt-get update no longer works, so if you did delete it then you'll need to run: sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status then sudo apt-get update will work again

Answer (score 0):

I run into kind of the same problem
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
W: Encountered status field in a non-version description

I replaced the dpkg status file with the status_old file. It fixed my problem.
 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Answer (score 0):

My `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file got deleted and according to apt I had no packages installed, as it determines them from the `status` file. I used the following method to regenerate the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file. The method worked very fine for me in Kali GNU/Linux, which is Debian-based.

### NOTE:

- This method assumes that all installed packages have created entries in the `/usr/share/doc` directory.
- This method starts from an empty `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file.
- This method may not work if you have more than 1 repository providing the same package. If you do have more than 1 repository providing the same package, temporarily disable the subsidiary repo, then delete the package cache lists for the repo in `/var/lib/apt/lists/`.

1. Delete the current `status` and `status-old` files. Make a backup of the files before deletion incase you get errors.

   ```
   mkdir ~/dpkg-status-backup
   cp /var/lib/dpkg/{status,status-old} ~/dpkg-status-backup
   rm /var/lib/dpkg/{status,status-old}
   ```
2. Get list of all packages installed, one package per line. 
   Note: it's `1` (one) not `l` (lower-case `L`).

   ```
   ls -1 /usr/share/doc > installed-packages.list
   ```
3. Rewrite the packages list into one line.

   ```
   tr '\n' ' ' < installed-packages.list > installed-packages-one-line.list
   ```
4. Create an empty `status` file to enable apt-cache to run.

   ```
   touch /var/lib/dpkg/status
   ```
5. Generate package records using apt-cache.

   ```
   cat installed-packages-one-line.list | xargs apt-cache show > raw-status-file
   ```
6. The `raw-status-file` may contain `Status:` fields for some packages. Delete them to avoid duplication.

   ```
   sed -i '/^Status:/d' raw-status-file
   ```
7. Add the `Status:`  field for every package to indicate to apt & dpkg that they're installed.

   ```
   sed -i 's/^Package:.*/&\nStatus: install ok installed/' raw-status-file
   ```
8. Remove fields unwanted by dpkg in `status` file: `SHA1:`, `SHA256:`, `MD5sum:`, `Description-md5:`, `Size:` & `Filename:` .

   ```
   sed -i '/^MD5sum:/d' raw-status-file
   sed -i '/^SHA1:/d' raw-status-file
   sed -i '/^SHA256:/d' raw-status-file
   sed -i '/^Size:/d' raw-status-file
   sed -i '/^Filename:/d' raw-status-file
   sed -i '/^Description-md5:/d' raw-status-file
   ```
9. The resultant `raw-status-file` after running the above commands is now the actual dpkg `status` file.

   ```
   mv raw-status-file status
   ```
10. Copy the `status` file to `/var/lib/dpkg/` as `status` and `status-old`.

    ```
    cp status /var/lib/dpkg/status
    cp status /var/lib/dpkg/status-old
    ```
11. Now run dpkg to validate your new status file. If you get errors, take hints from dpkg's error report, & solve accordingly. If you get no errors, then the `status` file has the correct syntax.

    ```
    dpkg --get-selections
    ```
12. Re-enable the disabled repos then run apt to update package cache lists to prevent the error `packages have unmet dependencies`.

    ```
    apt update
    ```
13. If you run into `packages have unmet dependencies` error in apt, then make sure you've enabled the subsidiary repos that provide the dependencies, then run aptitude. I prefer `aptitude` because it's better at solving package installation errors.

    ```
    aptitude full-upgrade
    ```

If you get no errors/your errors have been resolved from apt or dpkg, and get "*PACKAGE* is already the newest version..." when you try to install a program you're sure is already installed, such as `coreutils`, then you've successfully regenerated the dpkg `status` file.

Clean-up the temp files created and the backup.

```
rm installed-packages.list installed-packages-one-line.list status
rm -r ~/dpkg-status-backup
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1237232)