# How to recreate /var/lib/dpkg/status?

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.10

When I run `sudo apt update` in Ubuntu 18.10 I get this error message:

```
E: flAbsPath on /var/lib/dpkg/status failed - realpath (2: No such file or directory)
E: Could not open file  - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: Problem opening 
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

After running `sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status` it's showing this error message:

```
cp: cannot stat '/var/lib/dpkg/status-old': No such file or directory
```

Comment: What command did you run to get that output ?

Comment: It ought to be `sudo apt update`

Comment: Sounds very much like this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1216965/sudo-apt-get-error-flabspath-on-var-lib-dpkg-status-failed-no-such-file-or-d

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I rebuild a corrupt dpkg status file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4834/how-do-i-rebuild-a-corrupt-dpkg-status-file)

Comment: Also related: [Corrupt dpkg status file](https://askubuntu.com/q/527064/325633), [How to recreate /var/lib/dpkg/status?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/161866/80216) (on U&L) and [Sudo apt-get error: flAbsPath on /var/lib/dpkg/status failed - No such file or directory](https://superuser.com/q/1216965/354511) (on SU).

Answer (score 3):

Run the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/dpkg/{alternatives,info,parts,triggers,updates}
sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo apt-get download dpkg
sudo dpkg -i dpkg*.deb
sudo apt-get download base-files
sudo dpkg -i base-files*.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get check
```

Answer (score 2):

Restore the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file from its backup file (`/var/lib/dpkg/status-old`). Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Then run `sudo apt update` again.

---

If that doesn't work run the following commands:

```
sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/status  
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo reboot  
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Comment: After running this command its showing this error.

cp: cannot stat '/var/lib/dpkg/status-old': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

My `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file got deleted and according to apt I had no packages installed, as it determines them from the `status` file. I used the following method to regenerate the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file. The method worked very fine for me in Kali GNU/Linux, which is Debian-based.

### NOTE:

- This method assumes that all installed packages have created entries in the `/usr/share/doc` directory.
- This method starts from an empty `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file.
- This method may not work if you have more than 1 repository providing the same package. If you do have more than 1 repository providing the same package, temporarily disable the subsidiary repo, then delete the package cache lists for the repo in `/var/lib/apt/lists/`.

1. Delete the current `status` and `status-old` files. Make a backup of the files before deletion incase you get errors.

   ```
   mkdir ~/dpkg-status-backup
   cp /var/lib/dpkg/{status,status-old} ~/dpkg-status-backup
   rm /var/lib/dpkg/{status,status-old}
   ```
2. Get list of all packages installed, one package per line. 
   Note: it's `1` (one) not `l` (lower-case `L`).

   ```
   ls -1 /usr/share/doc > installed-packages.list
   ```
3. Rewrite the packages list into one line.

   ```
   tr '\n' ' ' < installed-packages.list > installed-packages-one-line.list
   ```
4. Create an empty `status` file to enable apt-cache to run.

   ```
   touch /var/lib/dpkg/status
   ```
5. Generate package records using apt-cache.

   ```
   cat installed-packages-one-line.list | xargs apt-cache show > raw-status-file
   ```
6. The `raw-status-file` may contain `Status:` fields for some packages. Delete them to avoid duplication.

   ```
   sed -i '/^Status:/d' raw-status-file
   ```
7. Add the `Status:`  field for every package to indicate to apt & dpkg that they're installed.

   ```
   sed -i 's/^Package:.*/&\nStatus: install ok installed/' raw-status-file
   ```
8. Remove fields unwanted by dpkg in `status` file: `SHA1:`, `SHA256:`, `MD5sum:`, `Description-md5:`, `Size:` & `Filename:` .

   ```
   sed -i '/^MD5sum:/d' raw-status-file
   sed -i '/^SHA1:/d' raw-status-file
   sed -i '/^SHA256:/d' raw-status-file
   sed -i '/^Size:/d' raw-status-file
   sed -i '/^Filename:/d' raw-status-file
   sed -i '/^Description-md5:/d' raw-status-file
   ```
9. The resultant `raw-status-file` after running the above commands is now the actual dpkg `status` file.

   ```
   mv raw-status-file status
   ```
10. Copy the `status` file to `/var/lib/dpkg/` as `status` and `status-old`.

    ```
    cp status /var/lib/dpkg/status
    cp status /var/lib/dpkg/status-old
    ```
11. Now run dpkg to validate your new status file. If you get errors, take hints from dpkg's error report, & solve accordingly. If you get no errors, then the `status` file has the correct syntax.

    ```
    dpkg --get-selections
    ```
12. Re-enable the disabled repos then run apt to update package cache lists to prevent the error `packages have unmet dependencies`.

    ```
    apt update
    ```
13. If you run into `packages have unmet dependencies` error in apt, then make sure you've enabled the subsidiary repos that provide the dependencies, then run aptitude. I prefer `aptitude` because it's better at solving package installation errors.

    ```
    aptitude full-upgrade
    ```

If you get no errors/your errors have been resolved from apt or dpkg, and get "*PACKAGE* is already the newest version..." when you try to install a program you're sure is already installed, such as `coreutils`, then you've successfully regenerated the dpkg `status` file.

Clean-up the temp files created and the backup.

```
rm installed-packages.list installed-packages-one-line.list status
rm -r ~/dpkg-status-backup
```

Comment: Could you summarize your solution in a nutshell?  So that your answer remains usable even if your link disappears for whatever reason.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1237235)

Comment: @Pilot6 should I copy over the whole answer from the other stackexchange community? 'Cause summarizing the answer would remove important details.

Comment: It's up to you. But a link answer is not an answer.