# dpkg: parse error

Tags: dpkg

I'm getting this error since the last few days while installing any package from the Software Center. I tried replacing the status file with any of the backup-status files in /var/backups/, but still getting the same error.

```
dpkg: parse error, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 114 package 'python-pkg-resources':
 `Depends' field, invalid package name `python:any': character `:' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters `-+._')
```

Due to less reputation I couldn't upload the screenshot but below I've numbered the lines as they are in the status file.

```
104.Package: python-pkg-resources 
105.Status: install ok installed
106.Priority: optional 
107.Section: python
108.Installed-Size: 182
109.Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
110.Architecture: all
111.Source: python-setuptools
112.Version: 3.3-1ubuntu1
113.Provides: python2.7-setuptools
114.Depends: python:any (>= 2.7), python:any (<< 2.8)
115.Suggests: python-distribute, python-distribute-doc
116.Conflicts: python-setuptools (<< 0.6c8-3)
117.Description: Package Discovery and Resource Access using pkg_resources
118.The pkg_resources module provides an API for Python libraries to
119.access their resource files, and for extensible applications and
120.frameworks to automatically discover plugins.  It also provides
121.runtime support for using C extensions that are inside zipfile-format
```

I'm able to install packages from source but whenever I try to install packages from either Software Centre or Synaptic Package Manager, I'm getting this error:

```
There seems to be a programming error in aptdaemon, the software that allows you to install/remove software and to perform other package management related tasks.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I rebuild a corrupt dpkg status file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4834/how-do-i-rebuild-a-corrupt-dpkg-status-file)

Comment: @DavidFoerster: thanks for your reply. I found that link before posting here and tried everything but still getting the same error. and whenever I try to install from Software centre I'm getting this error :                    "There seems to be a programming error in aptdaemon, the software that allows you to install/remove software and to perform other package management related tasks."

Comment: Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: It may help, if you post the section of `/var/lib/dpkg/status` around line 114.