# I need help with this error i keep getting when i try to install or do apt upgrade

Tags: dpkg, raspberrypi

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 32239 package 'x11-common':

 end of file during value of field 'Conffiles' (missing final newline)

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I am quite new to linux and cant find anything on this issue. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: To help you with this the version of Ubuntu needs to be in this question. This seems to be an error message without the command to caused it included. Please edit the question and put in what command you ran to get this error.

Answer (score 0):

The text file `/var/lib/dpkg/status` is used as a database of installed packages. In this file, every line should be terminated by a newline character. The error indicates that it is not the case. This in turn tells us the file is damaged. Maybe Linux froze while an update was running, maybe the hard disk was 100% full (check with `df -hl`) and the file could not be written. There are probably other reason that could explain why the file is corrupted.

First try to understand what went wrong, in particular make sure you don't have a full disk.

Then, you need to recover from this situation. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/5175/294070).